# Is this generalization of Big-Theta notation correct?

Tags: performance, algorithm, big-o, polynomial-math, asymptotic-complexity

Say you have an algorithm that completes in a polynomial number of steps for the input of size `n`, like, for example, `P(n)=2n^2+4n+3`.  The asymptotic tight bound for this algorithm `Θ(n^2)`.

Is it true to say that the Big-Theta notation for any algorithm is `n` to the power of the degree of the polynomial `P(n)`, or are there any cases where that is not true?

Comment: This doesn't account for Theta(log(n)), or Theta(2^n), or Theta(n!), etc

Comment: Yes, that is true for polynomials. (Of course, not all functions are polynomials.) Proving it from the definitions is a good exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity of polynomial time algorithms are bounded by **O(n<sup>k</sup>)**, where `0 < k ≤ ∞`. It doesn't mean that all the algorithms are having a polynomial time complexity. There are many algorithms with sub polynomial complexity. Examples include **O(k)** (constant complexity), **O(<sup>k</sup>√n)** (k<sup>th</sup> root of n, where `1 ≤ k ≤ ∞`), **O(log n)**, **O(log log n)**, etc. There are also algorithms which are having super polynomial time complexity. Examples for such complexities are **O(k<sup>n</sup>)**, where `1 < k ≤ ∞`, **O(n!)**, etc.